# Chrome extension fails to load when I add icons

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been learning how to make a Chrome extension and have been stuck on just adding an icon for a while now, I've copy pasted code that supposedly works but I keep getting this error:

```
Could not load icon 'icon16.png' specified in 'icons'.
Could not load manifest.
```

My code:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "extension",
    "description": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon48.png"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [
                "test.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "https://www.test.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've triple checked that every image is in fact a PNG and is of the right size. I have a single directory with `manifest.json`, `test.js`, and all three images (as well as a.prettierrc file, although I doubt that has any impact).

If I remove the icons part of `manifest.json` the extension works perfectly.

Comment: This is so simple, you should setup a github repo or something to share the actual code

Comment: Sounds like it's reading the manifest and looking for your file.   It's probably something simple like you naming the file "icons16.png" instead of "icon16.png", or using windows and hiding extensions so your file is really "icon16.png.png".   You can try adding a leading `/` though, like `"/icon16.png"`

Comment: I swear I looked at it a thousand times, somehow I managed to name the images logo16.png instead of icon16. thanks!

Comment: Been there myself :)

Answer (score 0):

The error about not being able to load the manifest is likely related to:

> "browser_action": {
> "default_icon": "icon48.png"
> },

which is from Manifest Version 2. The "browser_action" field should be changed to:

> "action": {
> "default_icon": "icon48.png"
> },

For further reference see here: [Action API unification](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#action-api-unification)